80's/90's anime about a mecha made out of bones
I need help finding a mecha anime that I have stuck in my head. I saw a clip of it on Instagram reels about 2-3 months ago and it refreshed before I could share or hit like and I was very interested in it.
It has a mecha that seems to be made out of bones and I think meat? (I could be wrong.) What I remember the most is the mecha stabbing the pilot with tentacles for some weird form of neural link (the pilot was visibly hurt). And the last thing I remember is the mecha unsheathing its sword from the spine (I think blood pours out?) and ends up extending into a very thin bony/metallic sword.

You initially tagged this as Gundam; have you checked G Gundam? It's been a long time since I've seen it but the titular G Gundam is pretty weird from what I recall.

This sounds very much like Escaflowne: The Movie.  The titular (fantasy) mecha in the movie version appears biomechanical, with armor made of bone-like material and flesh-like joints.  The pilot joins with it by giving it access to their blood via tentacles that pierce their neck. It can also deploy a sword in the fashion you've described.
See ~52 seconds in this trailer for the movie: 



There are also the dragons, whose skeletons appear multiple times in the series. The crystals powering the mecha ("Gymelefs" I believe they're called) are found within the bodies of dragons - and sometimes mined from their ossified remains.

Does this match your recollection, OP?
